# Travis CI - Maven build - Tests are skipped by default

Tags: maven, travis-ci

I observed that unit tests are skipped by default during travis-ci builds.

My travis config file

```
language: java
sudo: false

jdk:
  - openjdk11

cache:
  directories:
  - "$HOME/.m2/repository"
  - "$HOME/.sonar/cache"

addons:
  sonarcloud:
    organization: st-spring-samples
    token:
      secure: ${SONAR_TOKEN}

script:
  - mvn org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install sonar:sonar
```

My travis build output:
[image: travis-ci build output]

Can someone please let me know why travis-ci forces `-DskipTests=true` option in this case?

Comment: From travis-ci documentation: `Before running the build, Travis CI installs dependencies`. My build uses assembly plugin to assemble wiremock stubs generated during test execution as a separate jar. As tests are not executed, wiremock stubs are not generated and this causes assembly plugin to fail. Is there a way not to skip tests while installing dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to overcome the problem by making use of maven build profiles. Assembly plugin will be invoked only with an explicit build profile. So travis install dependencies phase doesn't kickoff assembly process, hence no assembly error.

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>assemble</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>io.spring.javaformat</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-javaformat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.0.15</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <inherited>true</inherited>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>validate</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>${project.artifactId}-mocks-${project.version}</finalName>
                            <attach>false</attach>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/wiremock-assembly.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>make-assembly</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>attach-mock-jar</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifacts>
                                        <artifact>
                                            <file>target/${project.artifactId}-mocks-${project.version}.jar</file>
                                            <type>jar</type>
                                            <classifier>mocks</classifier>
                                        </artifact>
                                    </artifacts>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.spring.javaformat</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-javaformat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.15</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <inherited>true</inherited>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>validate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Full `pom.xml` can be found [here](https://github.com/st-spring-samples/rest-client-exception-handling/blob/master/account-service/pom.xml)

I am still interested to see if there is a better option available. If anyone knows one, please let me know.